# Adding labels dynamically to a form: Labels not visible when trying to add more labels

Tags: c#

I use this code to add some labels to a windows form in c#:

```
Label[] lbl = new Label[temp+1];
for (int i = 0; i <= temp; i++) {
    lbl[i] = new Label();
    lbl[i].Text = "" + i;
    lbl[i].Location = new Point(30 + (i * unit), 380);
    lbl[i].Visible = true;
    this.Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
}
```

There is not a serious problem but my code works for temps less than 5 and for temps greater than 5 it shows only the first one.
What you think? where is the problem?

Comment: Not in the above code, is my guess. Do you do anything with `lbl` later?

Comment: No. Code is finished there after finishing this part. It works correct for temps less than 5

Comment: When temp is 5, do you still see the first four labels and just the fifth one is missing? Then I guess the form is just not wide enough to show any further labels with locations to the right.

Comment: @NineBerry no if I increase temp only show first one (I mean 0), Problem is not on form's width because "unit" has a small value related on the form width and temp. actually unit=width/temp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the labels automatically adjust their size to their content by setting their `AutoSize` property to `true`:

```
 lbl[i] = new Label();
 lbl[i].Text = "" + i;
 lbl[i].Location = new Point(30 + (i * unit), 380);
 lbl[i].Visible = true;
 lbl[i].AutoSize = true;
 this.Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
```

Without this, the labels have a fixed size. When this fixed size is greater than `unit`, the labels overlap and hide each other's text. With more labels to add, `unit` becomes smaller and then smaller than the default width of the labels when `temp` is ≥ 5.

Alternatively, you could set the labels' width to `unit` to make sure that they do not overlap.